# Using by moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Mx(t) =  \frac{e^{2t}-1}{2t}$  be a moment generating function of $ x $;if $ Y=3x_1 $
 then $My(t) =$? 
I cant solve this examples 
Pleas help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $Y=3X-1$ then  $M_Y(t)=Ee^{t(3X-1)}=Ee^{(3t)X} e^{-t}=\frac {(e^{6t}-1)} {6t}e^{-t}$.